# Does Card.io supports the cards with plain image? I mean non embossed cards

Tags: card.io

Trying to scan the card with non embossed numbers that is plain image card and its not getting scanned. wanted to know whether card.io supports non embossed cards also.

Answer (score 1):

There has been an issue reported on GitHub where they say that Card.io doesn't support non embossed cards.

For now, the only solution presented there is a "library" made for card.io, like an extension that helps it to read non embossed cards.

Here is the issue: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/283

Answer (score 0):

No. Card.io only supports embossed cards.

The project is not under active development.